# How can I have a URL like www.example.com/about?language=ja to set Japanese for the page?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I've enabled the Locale and Content Translation module but am having trouble understanding how to do something that it seems should be working.

Basically I have a page, we'll say '/about' and it's in English.

I click translate, I have a few languages enabled, so I click to add translation for Japanese. It brings up the interface for making a new page. I change some stuff to Japanese, and set the URL alias to be /about ('about') like the english page.

I've setup my language options to use the "Session" detection method.

The result I'm wanting to achieve, but not getting is to have:

```
www.example.com/about -- to go to english (this works)
www.example.com/about?language=ja -- to go to the Japanese translation, this does not work, it just loads up the English page.
```

It seems like this would be the normal functionality so I feel like I'm missing something here.

Comment: belongs on drupal.

Comment: www.example.com/ja/about ?

Comment: there are 4-5 methods of selecting a language.  That is using the 'URL' option.  I'm referencing the 'Session' option.

Answer (score 1):

just to be sure:
at admin/config/regional/language/admin_language, enable "Session" Detection method
make sure request/get parameter set to language
make sure you have about page in 'ja' language

try to visit yoursite.com/?language=japanese, it should be translating interface/etc - this way you can check translation is working.

Comment: I don't have any interfaces translated currently (I don't display any standard drupal interfaces to regular users anyway).  I have Session enabled, and there is a 'ja' version of the page, it even gives me a link to the Japanese version at the bottom of the page, but it links directly to the node so something like /node/123?language=ja instead of /about?language=ja.  I setup the URL alias but can't seem to access the japanese page with it by default.

Comment: /node/123?language=ja what this url is displaying? translated node?
try to clear cache at performance page, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Content Translation module is out-dated and was replaced by Entity Translation.  Content Translation doesn't seem to work with the Session Detection method (at least with URL Aliases), but Entity Translation works fine with it.