# How do you switch a site's language by using GET variables? Is there a module?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Currently I'm using [a module](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_website) that displays a bunch of nodes on a single page.

And I also have translated content in different languages.

The core functionality to switch a sites language currently creates a prefix in the URL, but is there one for switching the language via a GET variable like www.example.com/node/8?lang=german?

Comment: There is already another answer - you do not need a custom module it is already there: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/12273/28126

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Language Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_switcher) module for multiple Language.

> Language Switcher for Drupal 7 is an enhancement for core language switcher block in local module. It's very useful for websites with multi-languages where you want to display content in different languages side-by-side

Answer (score 0):

If you have any custom module installed in your Drupal site then I'd suggest to add 3-4 lines of code that can do this trick for you. Though you have to switch the language in the **hook_init** function in your module. Just reducing the overhead of installing new module.

In your custom module you can override the default language global object,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function CUSTOM_MODULE_hook_init() {
  if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang_code = check_plain($_GET['lang']);
    // Get the list of languages present in site.
    $languages = language_list();
    if (isset($languages[$lang_code])) {
      // Overwrite the global language object.
      global $language;
      $language = $languages[$lang_code];
    }
  }
}
```